# Binding a WPF DataGrid to a List<List<int>> object

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I try to **bind a DataGrid in WPF** to a **list of lists**.
I am doing this:

```
private List<List<int>> _rows = new List<List<int>>();

private void WindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
      {
           var row = new List<int>();

           for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
           {
               row.Add(j);
           }

           _rows.Add(row);
      }

      var dg1 = new DataGrid();

      for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
      {
           var col = new DataGridTextColumn();
           col.Header = i.ToString();
           dg1.Columns.Add(col);
      }

      dg1.ItemsSource = _rows;
      this.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(dg1);
}
```

When I run the program the DataGrid remains empty nothing works.
**how should I do to get this work?**

Answer (score 0):

You never acually add an int to any List. You added a `List<Int>` but never an `Int`.

You iterate rows (not columns) (_row.count will give you a row count) to add dg1 comlumns.

It needs more help that just this but this is a start

```
for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) 
{ 
    var row = new List<int>(); 

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
    {
        row.add(i);
    }

    _rows.Add(row); 
}
```

Comment: Thx @BalamBalam for the help , I missed that , I changed my code , but even with that it s still not working , it s giving me a datagrid with 2 additional columns which are Capacity and Count, don't see how to get the binding to list of list done

Comment: OK, have done something similar and got it to work.  Try List<array>.   If you look through my answers there is an example of where I did this.

Comment: This is the answer for dynamic columns.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959600/wpf-display-grid-of-results-with-dynamic-columns-rows/6961874#6961874

Answer (score 0):

You can't just bind a list of value types to a WPF DataGrid.
You need to create a wrapper class for the int and specify the binding, as specified in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/479419/61697).