# WPF Datagrid binding to list of arrays with Cell Template Column

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I have a datagrid which is bound to a List where each ViewModel has an array of fields indexed by strings e.g. RowVM["AKey"]. Using something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959600/wpf-display-grid-of-results-with-dynamic-columns-rows/6961874#6961874)
I can get a TextBlock to display the correct element e.g.

```
textColumn.Binding= new Binding("[" + columnHeaderText + "].Name");
```

But this only allows me to display one value, in the TextBlock.

I need to display two fields from the indexed property, so I thought I'd use a `DataGridTemplateColumn` instead of a `DataGridTextColumn`, but have not been able to get the new binding to link correctly to the column header text.

For each column my code is currently

```
tmpltColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
tmpltColumn.Header = t.FirstName + " " + t.LastName;
tmpltColumn.CellTemplate = TimeTableGrid.FindResource("TimeTableCellTemplate") as DataTemplate;
TimeTableGrid.Columns.Add(tmpltColumn);
```

where the `TimeTableCellTemplate` defines two text blocks.

If I define the Text for the TextBlocks as

```
Text="{Binding Column.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}}}"
```

then the text block correctly displays the Column Header.

What I can't do is find any binding for the textblocks that will locate the Column Header text and use it as the index.

[Edit:]

The binding for the original TextColumn was created when I built the column, and had the relevant key value hardcoded in the indexing brackets e.g. [columnHeaderText].Name (see the textColumn.Binding above).

When I move to TemplateColumns, the Template contains the Binding expression, and isn't specific to a particular column.

So I have the following (simplified):

```
                <DataGrid.Resources>
                    <DataTemplate x:Key="TimeTableCellTemplate" >
                        <StackPanel Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Orientation="Vertical" >
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Column.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}}}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGrid.Resources>
```

The Binding shown correctly displays the actual Column.Header in the `TextBlock`, but what I need to do is use that value in the indexing from the RowViewModel. In a fit of hopefulness I tried this i.e. embedding the Column.Header binding in the CellTemplate binding:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding [{Binding Column.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}}}].Name}" />
```

which of course didn't work.

Am I missing something blindingly obvious?

[end]

Is there a solution for this? or am I going to have to e.g. switch to a Grid and manually load each cell?

I don't need two-way binding, if that helps, although Drag and Drop to and from cells will be required.

Comment: describe this: `What I can't do is find any binding for the textblocks that will locate the Column Header text and use it as the index`

Comment: edited - hopefully clearer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution that works so far, following the pattern described in [this](http://our.componentone.com/groups/topic/creating-a-datatemplate-in-code-to-build-a-multiline-custom-column/) link.

The original version with a simple TextBlock hardcoded the key (the Column header) into the Binding e.g. `[key].Name`

The new version creates a template with nested TextBlocks with the same Bindings, again hardcoded.

for completeness, the complete code calls the following :

```
private DataGridTemplatColumn CreateColumn(string key)
{
    DataGridTemplateColumn tmpltColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
    tmpltColumn.Header = key;

    // Make the parts for the template
    FrameworkElementFactory tb = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
    Binding b = new Binding($"[{key}].Name");
    tb.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, b);

    FrameworkElementFactory tb1 = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
    Binding b1 = new Binding();
    b1.Path = new PropertyPath($"[{key}].Room");
    tb1.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, b1);

    FrameworkElementFactory sb = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));
    sb.AppendChild(tb);
    sb.AppendChild(tb1);
    DataTemplate dt = new DataTemplate { VisualTree = sb };
    dt.Seal();
    tmpltColumn.CellTemplate = dt;

    return tmpltColumn;
}
```

The template column is then added to the DataGrid, and all is well.

When I asked the question, I was wanting to make one template (defined in the XAML) work for all columns, which would seem to be more elegant, but this is simple and easy to understand, which is also good.